# Triangulation method for geolocation

Tags: rf

I’m trying to understand the triangulation method for geolocation.

I understand that the item that I need to find has some transmitter and the two receivers receive the signal emitted from the transmitter with some time delay between them, also the distance between the two receivers is known.

How can I deduce (mathematically) the angle to the transmitter from the time delay information?

Can anyone explain it mathematically?

Comment: this is rather a math problem

Comment: It takes a certain time for a signal to travel a certain distance. If there is no time difference, it means that the distances from both receivers to transmitter are equal and you have a triangle with two sides that have an equal length. But that's not enough information to know the angles - the transmitter might be right between two receivers on a straight line. You need more info to solve it.

Comment: Actually it's called trilateration and not triangulation.

Comment: Actually trilateration uses transmitted data with time to measure GPS positions without angles.  https://gisgeography.com/trilateration-triangulation-gps/  FYI @Andyaka

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 yes, I know, that's why I said the measurement method proposed in the question wasn't triangulation.

Comment: the question ought to be corrected for proper terms of location inputs and outcome. relative position or absolute coordinates

Answer (score 2):

I worked in passive ranging sonar for years which uses this method to determine the bearing to a target with 2 hydrophone arrays (a third array was used to determine range). The caveat is that you assume  the range is much greater than the distance between the two arrays (receivers). In that case, the signal paths from the target to the arrays can be taken as parallel. Then a simple right triangle   calculation yields the angle as follows: cos (angle) = Tc/L where T is the measured time delay, c is the speed of propagation and L is the distance between the two receivers. For submarine sonars, where L is on the order of 20 meters, and ranges are on the order of thousands of meters, the key assumption is valid.

Comment: Barry How did you get the angle equasion?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The setup you describe is just like [LORAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LORAN), but in reverse.

Knowing the TDOA (time difference of arrival) and the distance between the receivers defines a locus of possible points for the unknown device that lie on a hyperbola. You would need an additional source of information, such as a third receiver, to narrow the choice down to a single answer.